# Format (raw) partition windows 8 - cannot access it

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have just made a new installation of windows 8 to my computer and partioned the harddrive. The problem is that one partition is raw, that is its not formatted to a specifik filesystem yet. What I want to do In windows is to access this partition - I want to use it for media.
But I cannot access it since its not formatted. I can see the allocation space in te dismanager but if i cannot format it.

So my question is - how do I format it/make it accesible so I can use it in windows?
Is the only answer to startover with a new installation of the OS?

cincerely

Comment: Can yo post more details?  Are you getting errors creating the new partition?  What tools are you using or have you tried?